# Powershell Group Array of Hashes with Duplicates

Tags: arrays, powershell, collections, grouping, hashtable

I have the following dataset [Array of Hashes]:

**Assume `ID` is always unique**

---

```
$dataset = @(
    @{
        ID   = "1234567891"
        Code = "ABC1111"
    },
    @{
        ID   = "1234567892"
        Code = "ABC1111"
    },
    @{
        ID   = "1234567893"
        Code = "ABC1112"  
    },
    @{
        ID   = "1234567894"
        Code = "ABC1113"   
    },
    @{
        ID   = "1234567895"
        Code = "ABC1114"   
    },
    @{
        ID   = "1234567896"
        Code = "ABC1111"  
    }
)
```

What I am trying to do is to group the following dataset by `Code` key.

I already tried multiple methods such as piping `Group-By`, `Group-Object`, `Sort-Object` but I'm still not getting the result I want.

What result I am looking to return is a hashtable which looks like so [Or anything similar]:

```
$groupedDataset = @{
    ABC1111 = @("1234567891","1234567892","1234567896")
    ABC1112 = @("1234567893")
    ABC1113 = @("1234567894")
    ABC1114 = @("1234567895")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the hash tables to a PSCustomObjects, group it, then assign it to the new hash table:

```
$groupedDataset = @{}

$dataset |
    ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]$_ } |
    Group-Object -Property Code |
    ForEach-Object { $groupedDataset[$_.Name] = $_.Group.ID }
```

See [`Get-Help about_Object_Creation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_object_creation) for more information about using `[PSCustomObject]` to create custom objects from hash tables.

Answer (score 4):

To complement [Bacon Bits' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50533302/45375):

There is no strict need to provide *custom objects* as input to `Group-Object`; `[hashtable]` instances can be used as-is, as long as you use a *script-block argument* to access the entry to group by (PSv3+ syntax):

```
$ht = @{}
$dataset | Group-Object { $_.Code } | ForEach-Object { $ht[$_.Name] = $_.Group.Id }
```

Note the use of `{ $_.Code }` in lieu of `[-Property] Code`; the latter only works with bona fide *properties* (as opposed to hashtable entries; conversely, however, `{ $_.Code }` works in either scenario, though `Code`, if applicable, is faster).